# MarkLogic 7 Return Document that have a specific element

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-7

the `cts:element-value-query` in `MarkLogic 7` does not work like `MarkLogic 8`, I would like to return the documents that have an element without attention to its value 
my query is like:

```
cts:search(collection("My-Collection"),cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("Element1"), ""))
```

I would like to return all of the documents that have the `Element1` in `MarkLogic 7`!!??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
cts:search(
  collection("My-Collection"),
  cts:element-query(xs:QName("Element1"), cts:and-query(()) )
)
```

Should work in all MarkLogic versions.

HTH!